# Docker Dependency visibility issue in maven multi-module project

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, layer, multi-module

I have Spring Boot project with a multi-module structure. Here is a part of my parent pom.xml.:

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>bank-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>migration</module>
        <module>data-access</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>admin-api</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>--enable-preview</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.10</version>
            </plugin>
    <plugins>
   </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.10</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
Dependency Relationships:

The migration module doesn't depend on other modules;
The data-access module depends on the migration module;
The core module depends on the data-access;
The admin-api module depends core module.
```

I try to dockerize the application. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# BUILD STAGE
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17-slim as builder

WORKDIR /build

# Copy the dependency specifications
COPY pom.xml pom.xml

COPY migration/pom.xml migration/pom.xml
COPY data-access/pom.xml data-access/pom.xml
COPY core/pom.xml core/pom.xml
COPY admin-api/pom.xml admin-api/pom.xml

RUN mvn -B install:install-file -Dfile=pom.xml -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=bank-app -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=pom

# Resolve dependencies for `migration` module
RUN mvn -q -ntp -B -pl migration -am dependency:go-offline
COPY migration migration
RUN mvn -q -B -e -pl migration install -DskipTests

# Resolve dependencies for `data-access` module
RUN mvn -q -ntp -B -pl data-access -am dependency:go-offline
COPY data-access data-access
RUN mvn -q -B -e -pl data-access install -DskipTests

# Resolve dependencies for `core` module
RUN mvn -q -ntp -B -pl core -am dependency:go-offline
COPY core core
RUN mvn -q -B -pl core install -DskipTests

# Resolve dependencies for `admin-api` module
RUN mvn -q -ntp -B -pl admin-api -am dependency:go-offline
# Copy sources for `admin-api` module
COPY admin-api admin-api
# Build the application
RUN mvn -q -ntp -B -pl migration,data-access,core,admin-api package -DskipTests

# Create a directory for JAR layers
RUN mkdir -p /jar-layers
WORKDIR /jar-layers

# Extract JAR layers
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar /build/admin-api/target/*.jar extract

# FINAL STAGE
FROM openjdk:17-alpine3.14

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy JAR layers
COPY --from=builder /jar-layers/dependencies/ ./dependencies/
COPY --from=builder /jar-layers/spring-boot-loader/ ./spring-boot-loader/
COPY --from=builder /jar-layers/snapshot-dependencies/ ./snapshot-dependencies/
COPY --from=builder /jar-layers/application/ ./application/

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

The problem is that my admin-api jar can't find dependencies that are in .m2/repository folder. However, as i understand every jar should be independent and contain info about all the dependencies it needs.

```
Step 24/32 : RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar /build/admin-api/target/admin-api-*.jar extract
 ---> Running in cda4ca308177
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.company.adminapi.AdminApiApplication.main(AdminApiApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Why do you need something like `RUN mvn -B install:install-file -Dfile=pom.xml -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=bank-app -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=pom
` ????